# Best Way to Visually Represent This Algorithm?

Tags: python

Just wondering what the best way to visually represent this algorithm program might be? We want to visually represent the shortest path and the packet moving through the routers if possible? Any ideas? Looking at turtle it seems we could achieve what we want. Any pointers welcome. Thanks.

Trying to visually represent this: displays shortest path between group of weighted (number value) nodes.

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop # for priority queue
pq = []

class node:
    label = ''
    # adjacency list of the node 
    neighbors = [] # list of nodes
    distances = [] # distances to neighbors
    # for Dijkstra
    prevNode = None
    totalDistance = float('Inf')
    visited = False
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        self.neighbors = []
        self.distances = []
        self.prevNode = None
        self.totalDistance = float('Inf')
        self.visited = False


# find the shortest paths to all nodes recursively
def dijkstra(node):
    # visit all neighbors and update them if necessary
    for i in range(len(node.neighbors)):
        n = node.neighbors[i]
        d = node.distances[i]
        if n.totalDistance > d + node.totalDistance:
            n.prevNode = node
            n.totalDistance = d + node.totalDistance
            heappush(pq, (n.totalDistance, n))
    node.visited = True

    (d, ne) = heappop(pq)
    if not ne.visited:
        dijkstra(ne)

# get the shortest path to the given node
def route(endNode):
    node = endNode
    labels = [endNode.label]
    # distances = []
    while node.label != node.prevNode.label:
        # distances.append(node.totalDistance - node.prevNode.totalDistance)
        node = node.prevNode
        labels.append(node.label)
    labels.reverse()
    return labels
    # distances.reverse()
    # return (labels, distances)

# create a graph
a = node('a')
b = node('b')
c = node('c')
d = node('d')
e = node('e')
f = node('f')
g = node('g')
graph = (a, b, c, d, e, f, g)

# create bidirectional edges of the graph
edges = []
edges.append((b, c, 3))
edges.append((d, e, 1))
edges.append((b, d, 2))
edges.append((c, e, 1))
edges.append((a, b, 1))
edges.append((a, d, 1))
edges.append((c, f, 1))
edges.append((e, f, 3))
edges.append((e, g, 1))

# create adjaceny list of neighbors for each node
for edge in edges:
    edge[0].neighbors.append(edge[1])
    edge[0].distances.append(edge[2])
    edge[1].neighbors.append(edge[0])
    edge[1].distances.append(edge[2])

# print the graph
print 'The graph:'
print
for n in graph:
    print 'Node: ', n.label
    print 'Neighbors:'
    for i in range(len(n.neighbors)):
        print n.neighbors[i].label, n.distances[i]
    print

# find the shortest paths to all neighbors starting w/ the given node
startNode = a
print 'Route start node:', startNode.label
startNode.prevNode = startNode
startNode.totalDistance = 0
dijkstra(startNode)

##print
##print 'The graph after Dijkstra:'
##print
##for n in graph:
##    print 'Node:', n.label
##    print 'totalDistance:', n.totalDistance
##    print 'prevNode:', n.prevNode.label
##    print

# print the shortest path to the given node
endNode = f
print 'Route end node:', endNode.label
print 'Route:', route(endNode)
print 'Total distance:', endNode.totalDistance
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/), and style the chosen edges differently.

Answer (score 0):

Display all the nodes with the distances between them proportional to the weight of the path between them. Then connect each pair which is a part of the shortest path with a directed line.

You can use `networkx` and `graphvis` to create such a diagram in Python.